# Share powershell functions for other scripts on multiple machines?

Tags: powershell

I have several functions which are called by many scripts located on the same or different machines on the same network (Company LAN). Is it possible to save/host these functions in one script instead of copy/paste them to every scripts?

```
function CommonFunc1($p1, $p2) { .... }
function SharedFunc2($p1, $p2, $p3) { .... }
```

Comment: I suppose it depends. Are the computers on the same network for example? Can they talk to each other? Are the functions in a module? More details would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, all the computer are on the same network. Right now the functions are not in a module but it can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a module for the function to go in, and put that module on a computer that's reachable by all others via drive mapping or network share etc. Then you can import the module from that machine.

Like this:

```
Import-Module \\machine-name\C$\path\to\module\module.psm1
```